# optimization of pairwise L2 distance computations

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, for-loop, bsxfun

I need help optimizing this loop. `matrix_1` is a (`n`x  2) int matrix and `matrix_2` is a (`m` x 2), `m` & `n` very.

```
index_j = 1;
for index_k = 1:size(Matrix_1,1)
    for index_l = 1:size(Matrix_2,1)
        M2_Index_Dist(index_j,:) = [index_l, sqrt(bsxfun(@plus,sum(Matrix_1(index_k,:).^2,2),sum(Matrix_2(index_l,:).^2,2)')-2*(Matrix_1(index_k,:)*Matrix_2(index_l,:)'))];
        index_j = index_j + 1;
    end
 end
```

I need `M2_Index_Dist` to provide a (`(n*m)` x 2) matrix with the index of `matrix_2` in the first column and the distance in the second column.

Output example:

```
M2_Index_Dist = [ 1, 5.465
                  2, 56.52
                  3, 6.21
                  1, 35.3
                  2, 56.52
                  3, 0
                  1, 43.5
                  2, 9.3
                  3, 236.1
                  1, 8.2
                  2, 56.52
                  3, 5.582]
```

Comment: Why are you applying `bsxfun` to two _scalar_ values? Can you give a small numerical example of the result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @FireSky: A numerical example should include input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to apply `bsxfun` with your formula (`||A-B|| = sqrt(||A||^2 + ||B||^2 - 2*A*B)`):

```
d = real(sqrt(bsxfun(@plus, dot(Matrix_1,Matrix_1,2), ...
    bsxfun(@minus, dot(Matrix_2,Matrix_2,2).', 2 * Matrix_1*Matrix_2.')))).';
```

You can avoid the final transpose if you change your interpretation of the matrix.

Note: There shouldn't be any complex values to handle with `real` but it's there in case of very small differences that may lead to tiny negative numbers.

---

Edit: It may be faster without `dot`:

```
d = sqrt(bsxfun(@plus, sum(Matrix_1.*Matrix_1,2), ...
    bsxfun(@minus, sum(Matrix_2.*Matrix_2,2)', 2 * Matrix_1*Matrix_2.'))).';
```

Or with just one call to `bsxfun`:

```
d = sqrt(bsxfun(@plus, sum(Matrix_1.*Matrix_1,2), sum(Matrix_2.*Matrix_2,2)') ...
    - 2 * Matrix_1*Matrix_2.').';
```

Note: This last order of operations gives identical results to you, rather than with an error `~1e-14`.

---

Edit 2: To replicate `M2_Index_Dist`:

```
II = ndgrid(1:size(Matrix_2,1),1:size(Matrix_2,1));
M2_Index_Dist = [II(:) d(:)];
```

Comment: Thanks that is useful but can you pull the index of matrix_2 out at the same time?

Comment: @FireSky Wouldn't that just be `idx = repmat(1:size(Matrix_2,1),1,size(Matrix_1,1));`? Or see new edit.

Comment: @FireSky Just a courteous bump. My last edit gave all you needed and everything is vectorized. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this does what you want:

```
ind = repmat((1:size(Matrix_2,1)).',size(Matrix_1,1),1); %'// first column: index
d = pdist2(Matrix_2,Matrix_1); %// compute distance between each pair of rows
d = d(:); %// second column: distance
result = [ind d]; %// build result from first column and second column
```

As you see, this code calls [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/pdist2.html) to compute the distance between every pair of rows of your matrices. By default this function uses Euclidean distance.

If you don't have `pdist2` (which is part of the the Statistics Toolbox), you can replace line 2 above with `bsxfun`:

```
d = squeeze(sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,Matrix_2,permute(Matrix_1, [3 2 1])).^2,2)));
```

Comment: if you tic toc pdist2 and the sqrt algorithm; pdist2 is about .00026sec when sqrt algorithm takes about .00004 sec

Comment: I use it multiple time throughout my code and would like to stay uniform while cutting out time

Comment: Try with the `bsxfun` version. On my machine, `pdist2` or `bsxfun` are faster than your loops

Comment: The sqrt referred to in the comment above is the one in the question and it has bsxfun in it. However the bsxfun algorithm you have (starting with squeeze) tic toc's at .00012 sec

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. My code is faster than yours on my computer. And  if your loop code is really faster for you (recent Matlab versions are said to run loops pretty well), I doubt you can improve that with Matlab

Comment: I guess I was hoping someone knew how to pull the index of the matrices without nesting loops. Oh well, I have many lines that need to be optimize but I do this one a few times so I was just hoping.

Comment: @FireSky You can stick to the formula you use without looping (see my answer), although I don't think it's much better than `pdist` or the `bsxfun` formula used by Luis here.

Comment: @FireSky Perhaps you only see a benefit with a larger `n`, `m`. Around 256, say. In this case, your code takes about 5 seconds to run, even when put in a function and saved in an M file.